# JDBC connection stops working between computers

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I've been working on a program which has a Microsoft Access database behind it and while it was working perfectly on the PC I started on I have just transferred it to another PC and I get this error when trying to connect to the database:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I've had no luck trying things I've found while searching around (mainly checking ODBC Data Sources) so hopefully I can get some specific advice for my setup. The two PCs are both Windows 7 and both have Microsoft Access 2010.

Comment: Can you open the database in Access on PC 2?

Comment: Yes [comment too short]

Comment: Have you [Set Up an ODBC Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on PC 2?

Comment: MS Access Database is already added

Comment: Hmm OK, turns out I don't have an ODBC icon in Control Panel, could that be the same problem?

Comment: **(1)** If the new machine already has the full Access application on it, is it the 32-bit version of Access, or is it the 64-bit version? **(2)** Is your Java application running under a 32-bit JVM (Java Virtual Machine), or is it running under a 64-bit JVM?

Comment: Good shout - 32-bit Access and 64-bit JVM (I thought it was running a 32-bit JVM as I had selected a 32-bit JRE installation in Installed JREs... turns out I had to create a new workspace to make it run a 32-bit JVM... odd). Anyway, the program is now running, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As revealed in the comments to the question, the problem was that the new machine had 32-bit Access installed (and therefore the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine) but the Java application was running under a 64-bit JVM (Java Virtual Machine). Switching the Java application to run under a 32-bit JVM solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (changing the DBQ path as appropriate), note this is `ODBC` not `JDBC` and is thus using the 
[JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC-ODBC_Bridge#Type_1_Driver_-_JDBC-ODBC_bridge)

```
Driver=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
Source=jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/MyDbDir/MyDBFolder/MyDB.mdb;
```

You might also consider using [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/), the Java Library for MS Access.